# Dependency injection / testability - would this logic be appropriate?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

In a testability perspective, would this logic be appropriate?

```
public class Foo {

    public List<SomeClass> Elements {get; set;}

    public Foo(IServiceInterface service) {
       this.Elements = service.GetElements();
    }    
}
```

or this would be the right way:

```
public class Foo {

    public List<SomeClass> Elements {get; set;}

    public Foo(List<SomeClass> elements) {
       this.Elements = elements;
    }    
}
```

When testing the Foo class, how i know that i need to mock or fake the GetElements method of `IDataAccess`?

Comment: Just curious. In #1 you are telling `Elements are somewhere, go an look for them through this magic interface` but then the `setter` says `nevermind, they will come to you eventually. Or never, Or they could, but they could be null!`.  Quite confusing. In any case, if elements are important for Foo's initialization, better solve the `Element` collection and then pass it as argument (#2). It makes Foo less dependent on anything, hence simpler to reason about and simpler to test too.

Comment: In the example shown a reasonable solution is to get rid of `Foo` altogether. `Foo` is a class that exists to call `IServiceInterface.GetElements()`.

Answer (score 4):

You can do both, depending on the role your class plays in the application. Note that if you go with the second case, you still need to get that data from *somewhere*, so you'll likely also have some other class that looks like your first example.

Regarding the first example: constructors shouldn't do extensive work, and you have no way of guaranteeing that an implementation of `IServiceInterface` will adhere to that. Don't call `IServiceInterface.GetElements` right away, but store the `service` reference to a private member field, and get the elements at some other, more appropriate time (you'll have to decide when and where that happens based on your knowledge of the domain, and the flow of control through the code).

That said, if you are doing TDD, a really important point regarding those tests is rapid feedback, so *all* of your tests should execute in a few seconds (or faster). You cannot have this if you need to pull data over from a database, over a network, or something potentially slow like that - so those are good things to mock. You don't want to be dependent on such things in your test anyway. You can also mock for other reasons - say, when you need a test-specific implementation of a service that gives you a simpler concrete interface and a better control over its behavior (like, what kind of things it returns or does). I'm mostly talking about the short-cycle "development-driving" tests here; there are other kinds of tests like integration tests - see David Arno's answer.

The kind of classes like the one in your first example are often somewhere in the "outer" layer, at the boundaries of the application, where they communicate with things like a database, a web service, or where they consume user input. Your second example is more like a class that you'll find in an inner layer, where the core logic of the application resides (although you can certainly find classes with similar dependency structure elsewhere).

When you are passing in a collection to some object, if that collection doesn't have to be a list, it's often more flexible to pass it as an `IEnumerable<T>` (internally you can store it as `IEnumerable<T>` as well, or you can convert it to something concrete like `List<T>` if that makes more sense in that specific case). In your tests, with this kind of classes you often just pass them an ad hoc collection, but that's not the only option.

Finally, you don't want to write tests that know the internal details of the system under test. Initially, you'll have just a few classes, and internal details will just be the code inside those classes. But, as the code grows, you'll pull stuff out into new classes, or create brand new interfaces and classes, and some of these will be completely internal to the system. Write your tests in terms of the "outer" classes and interfaces - these should be expressive enough so that you can write all your test cases without having to reference the internals. This is so that you can refactor. Refactoring is about changing the internal structure of the code without changing the functionality, and without changing the tests - since they serve as a safety net, to alert you if you've broken something. If your tests depend on the internal stuff (implementation details), then they get in your way (as in, when you change the structure, you get compiler errors). Sometimes, you'll realize that the "surface level" code has the wrong structure, or that it doesn't provide the right interfaces for what you need, so you'll have to restructure it, and the tests as well - but that's different from refactoring.

I know you were probably hoping for a simpler answer, but it is what it is - there's a bit of depth here, and a lot of this requires developing intuition, and you can only do that by practicing TDD for a while.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, are there other parts of the code (outside of `Foo`) that need to modify `Elements`? If not, get rid of that `set`. Secondly, as a complete aside, a `_` suffix normally denotes a field in C#, not a parameter. So I'd change the name to just `dataAccess`.

The rule of thumb on whether you need a mock implementation of `IDataAccess` is that you need one if a call to `dataAccess.GetElements()` can have side effects (such as accessing a database), is slow or it's complex to set up the runtime implementation. So if any of those apply, use a mock for unit tests, otherwise avoid it and use the real class.

Even then, you may want to create integration tests to access the real database, but be careful here as they are often brittle tests that can easily break if the database isn't set up correctly and can be slow so you likely won't want to run them as often as your unit tests.

Comment: Thanks, apart the potentially problem of database access, by a concept perspective, by looking only at the method signature, i don't know that my class requires to call the GetElements() method, so maybe the logic is wrong?

Comment: Removing `set` from `Elements` wouldn't help much. Any caller could still clear the list and repoulate it with anything they want. I'd use `IEnumerable<SomeClass>` as the property's type and use `yield return` to return the single elements.

Comment: @ʞᴉɯ: "i don't know that my class requires to call the GetElements()" - you don't need to know, and (generally speaking) you shouldn't know how and when the class calls this method, as that's normally an implementation details. All you need to know is that this requires something that implements `IServiceInterface`, and if you want to implement that interface, you *have* to provide the `GetElements()` method (the compiler will protest otherwise), in a way that makes sense for the implementing class (and assume it will be called). 
P.S. Cool nick, but hard to @ reference in comments.

Answer (score 1):

Both approaches are exactly equivalent from their flexibility, expressiveness, and testability. For example, in the case that we have a Service but the constructor of your class takes a list, then just call it as:

```
new Foo(service.GetElements())
```

It really doesn't matter whether the `GetElements()` method is called within the constructor or outside of it, you get the same object either way.

Given two equally expressive designs, which should you use? The simpler one. Here, the design *without* the service interface is simpler. In a sense, that interface is just an unnecessary complication.

In some cases, using that service interface could still be sensible: when construction of the list may be deferred, or if it is constructed more than once. But in that case you wouldn't have a choice, the approach without the interface would simply not meet your requirements. But since you do have a choice, that interface is clearly unnecessary here.

Answer (score 1):

## My personal favourite

```
public class Foo
{
    private readonly List<SomeClass> _elements = new List<SomeClass>();


    public List<SomeClass> Elements => _elements.ToList();


    public void Add(SomeClass someClass)
    {
        _elements.Add(someClass);
    }

}
```

## Reasons

The reasons for this design are:

- The list belongs to `Foo`. `.Add()`, `.Clear()` and all the other things you can do to the list is none of other classes' business. So the `List` is private, and if something else wants to have the list, they only get a copy (`_elements.ToList()`). This way, other code can't change what belongs to `Foo`.
- Having an empty list might make sense, but having a `null` list does not. That's why we set it `readonly` and immediately initialize it to an empty list. It will now never be `null`.
- In most cases we actually want the list to contain something, so we can add elements via the `Add(SomeClass someClass)` method. It only calls the same method on our list, but the difference is that the code clearly communicates "I want it to be possible to add items to the list".

## Caveats

Those are the reasons I *most often* encountered when making a class like this. Not all situations are alike and you might have reasons to do things differently.

For example, this code is optimized for readability and clarity, but maybe your application becomes slow. You *measure* performance and find out that, because you're working with millions of elements, copying the whole list is taking too much time. In that case, performance counters readability and `_elements.ToList();` won't do it.

In general, I would say this design is a good *starting point* - and because it is well encapsulated, you can change things later easily. For example, if you later want to use a `HashSet` instead of a `List`, you can do that without changing anything else but `Foo`.

If you're using a DI framework, you'll have to use a factory (or similar initialization logic) in order to call `Add(SomeClass someClass)`.

## Alternatives for element access

`public List<SomeClass> Elements => _elements.ToList();` is *my* personal favourite, mainly because it's the most succinct. Here are some alternatives:

```
// Using a statement body instead of an expression body
// This does the same, just in a more verbose way - but if you're working
// with an older C# version you might HAVE to use this instead.
public List<SomeClass> Elements 
{
    get { return _elements.ToList(); }
}


// Creating a copy "manually" instead of with LINQ
// Slightly longer. LINQ's ToList() actually just makes a null check and then does this.
public List<SomeClass> Elements => new List<SomeClass>(_elements);


// Returning an IEnumerable instead of a list via "manually" iterating the list.
// Mentioned by Thomas Schremser in a comment to another answer.
// This would be a nice performance compromise:
// It keeps the encapsulation, but doesn't create a copy of the list.
// However, arguably less readable, if just for taking 10 lines instead of 1.
public IEnumerable<SomeClass> Elements
{
    get
    {
        foreach (SomeClass someClass in _elements)
        {
            yield return someClass;
        }
    }
}
```